# CADisplayLink frameInterval fps difference when using multiple OpenGL views

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, cadisplaylink

So this isn't exactly a real problem for me, but I would just like to know if anyone knows why this is happening.

I have 2 views that are side by side, although only one is visible at a time on screen, but both are active at the same time (need responsive swiping so dont want to destroy the views when they go off the screen). now when i just had the one view done, a `frameInterval` of 2 would result in a fps of 30, which is normal. when i added the second view, a `frameInterval` of 2 resulted in 60fps. I changed it to 4 on both views and then I started getting 30 fps as i intended.

Im not sure why its like this but i would like to know. Seems like a bug or something to me.

Comment: Where do you read this FPS? I think the counter in xCode counts "presentRenderbuffer" calls per second and in that case when having 2 views running 30 FPS results in summing the calls up achieving 2*30 FPS. Try to manually count the frames in one of the views.

Comment: im reading it off xcodes fps counter under the debug navigator. maybe its fooling xcodes fps counter, i should try my own counting to see